# Error connecting to node server with socket

Tags: node.js, angular, express, websocket

I have a node server running with socket.io implemented by someone else

```
var milo_socket_io = io
                    .of('/milo')
                    .on('connection', function(socket)
                    {
                        console.log("Client connected " + socket.id);
                        clients.push(socket);
                    });

function sendLiveData(jsonStr)
{
    switch (jsonStr.deviceType)
    {
        case 'milo' :
            milo_socket_io.emit('data', JSON.stringify(jsonStr));
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Should not happen. Device Type " + jsonStr.deviceType)
    }
}
```

I am trying to connect to it from angular . I tried this

```
 ret_data:any;

  connect(){
    this.socket = socketio('http://ip:port',{transports: ['websocket']}
    )
    console.log(this.socket.id)
    this.socket.on('data',(res) => this.ret_data = res )
    return this.ret_data
  }
```

Both socket.id and ret_data are undefined when i try to console.log(). Where am I doing wrong. Spare me if its some basic mistake.I just started with sockets.
I get status code 101:Switching protocols. Does that mean connection is established successfully or not?
 Thank you

Comment: I have tried this.socket.on('error', console.error) in connect function, still nothing in console

Comment: Look on the server side, do you receive "Client connected" ?

Comment: I don't have access to the server side.

Comment: Isn't there any way I can check the connection from client side ?

Comment: Probably what you need is a namespace for socket.io and not a route